# Capybara config after each page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, poltergeist

I'm looking for a generic way to configure RSpec Capybara to do something after each page load within test example.

Example:

```
config.after_page_load do
  execute_script('window.analyticsEvents = []; window.analytics = function(name, properties) { analyticsEvents.push([name, properties]) }')
end
```

Then I can check that array in my feature test.

Only other option for a "global" configuration that I can think of is use `if Rails.env.test?` in the view.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Conditionally running JS in the view is the only thing I could think of. * *shudders* *

Comment: Ah, yeah. That's what I ended up doing. I thought  there might be a more cleaver way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could patch `#visit` to always execute your JS after each visit call - but it seems like maybe you're trying to do something that Capybara really isn't meant for, and may not make sense to be doing.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I'm not always calling visit. Most of the time it's just redirect via clicking buttons on the page

Comment: @PetrGazarov Then there's no way to do it from Capybara -- it doesn't know about page changes triggered that way unless you're specifically checking for visible changes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while trying to [monitor slow network requests](https://gist.github.com/Jamedjo/e8ebf79c16dc5abda4786bc952f89a37). While it wasn't needed in the end, the following worked successfully:

```
module CapybaraHooks
  def after_page_change

  end

  Capybara::Session::DSL_METHODS.each do |method|
    define_method method do |*args, &block|
      old_page = page.current_url
      super(*args, &block)
      new_page = page.current_url

      puts "Command #{method}"
      if old_page != new_page
        puts "Changed from #{old_page} to #{new_page}"
        after_page_change
      else
        puts "Still on page: #{new_page}"
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include CapybaraHooks, type: :feature
end
```